# Android Speech Recognition for specific sound pitch

Tags: android, api

Can we detect 'scream' or 'loud sound' etc using Android Speech Recognition APIs?
Or is there is any other software/third party tool that can do the same?

Thanks,
Kaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean implement a clapper?

There's no need to use fancy math or the speech recognition API. Just use the MediaRecorder and its getMaxAmplitute() method.

Here is some of code you'll need.
The algorithm, records for a period of time and then measures the amplitute difference. If it is large, then the user probably made a loud sound.

```
public void recordClap()
{
    recorder.start();

    int startAmplitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    Log.d(D_LOG, "starting amplitude: " + startAmplitude);
boolean ampDiff;
do
{
    Log.d(D_LOG, "waiting while taking in input");
    waitSome();
    int finishAmplitude = 0;
    try
    {
        finishAmplitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
        Log.e(D_LOG, "unable to get the max amplitude " + re);
    }
    ampDiff = checkAmplitude(startAmplitude, finishAmplitude);
    Log.d(D_LOG, "finishing amp: " + finishAmplitude + " difference: " + ampDiff );
}
while (!ampDiff && recorder.isRecording());
```

}

```
private boolean checkAmplitude(int startAmplitude, int finishAmplitude)
{
    int ampDiff = finishAmplitude - startAmplitude;
    Log.d(D_LOG, "amplitude difference " + ampDiff);
    return (ampDiff >= 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were trying to detect a scream or loud sound, I would just look for a high root-mean-squared of the sounds coming through the microphone. I suppose that you can try to train a speech recognition system to recognize a scream, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: Well, no. I haven't actually coded for the Android for one thing. I've just done various sound programs. Also, this isn't a 'give me the codes' site. Give it a shot and post your code asking for help if it isn't working. Look up root-mean-squared. You'll basically just take a period of time, square the values, find the mean of those values, and then take the square root of the mean. The square root can actually be skipped really for this usage. Then you just need to look at the values you are getting when screaming versus talking/quiet and set a correct threshold.

Comment: I think your answer is not helpful. I can't vote down yet so this is the alternative'